# How to change brightness on puppy linux?

Tags: linux, laptop, brightness, acpi, puppylinux

I just installed puppy linux but the screen is literally burning my eyes. The `Fn+Brightness` key on my laptp doesn't work, I tried to go to setup and change the gamma but it just make the colors darker, the screen itself keeps being extremly bright so I think it's due to the backlight. How can I diminish the backlight or the thing that keeps the screen bright despite me lowering gamma ?

Also when I'm in command prompt mode (GUI closed) the screen is still very bright. Is there a way to fix that too ?

Changing the brightness file with `echo X >/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness` has no effect at all

I managed to add `acpi_backlight=vendor`in grub as you can find on the internet to fix this problem but this doesn't change anything. Pressing `Fn+arrow` still doesn't work and changing the brightness file in acpi_video doesn't work either.

I have a Samsung RV515

Comment: I don't know how many Puppy Linux experts there are on Super User, but if you don't get a good answer, try the Puppy Linux forum: http://murga-linux.com/puppy/.  That has the highest concentration of subject matter experts and I have always successfully gotten my questions answered there.

Comment: @fixer1234 i despise that old forum model but i'll give it a try thanks